# Postgres pg_dump restore performance. Is using pg_dump to back up large databases an acceptable solution

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, pg-dump, write-ahead-logging, pg-restore

Folks,
I am considering moving from SQL Server to Postgres. The per core licensing of SQL Server is too expensive for my needs.

My one concern is restoring Postgres from a dump. I believe that the pg_dump creates a file of SQL commands to build back up the DB and that this can be quite slow.

I am used to restoring large SQL Server databases in quite a short period of time.

Can anyone advise me here on what folks do for performant disaster recover solutions?

I am installing postgres on windows, so barman etc are probably not an option and without some backup software I would be concerned about doing WAL point in time restores manually. I believe you need to shut down the server and restore everything and that seems severe.

Comment: `pg_dump` can also create a dump file that is not a SQL script using the "custom" or "directory" formats. You can easily setup a slave that is replicated to support desaster recovery. Alternatively use `pg_basebackup` to clone your server

Comment: [wal-e](https://github.com/wal-e/wal-e) and [omnipitr](https://github.com/omniti-labs/omnipitr) are implemented in Pyhon so you might get those to run on Windows. But implementing WAL archiving is pretty easy in Windows and the "manual restore" isn't that complicated either using some batch files

Comment: [pghoard](https://github.com/aiven/pghoard) is another Python based tool

Comment: I don't know, horse... That WAL archive restore looks a bit mental in the official docs.    Do you know if anyone successfully used any of these python backup tools on a windows machine

Comment: WAL archive restore is essentially a `copy` command. There is no "magic" to it

Comment: Ah I see a walkthrough of the windows WAL archive and restore process here where he is using powershell. I'll give it a go. thanks horse. https://stefanprodan.com/2014/postgresql-base-backup-automation/

Comment: So I went through that document and I was able run the base backup then turn the server off, delete the data directory and unpackage the tar files from the backup in there. I have created a recovery.conf and restarted the server. The instance only contained one database with one table with one column and one value yet 4 hours later its still in recovery. How can I troubleshoot this stuck in recovery scenario?

Comment: ..recovery.conf has not changed to recovery.done.. here is what recovery.conf looks like... standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'host=localhost port=5432..'

Comment: So I was able to get out of recovery by stopping the server and manually setting the recovery.conf file to recovery. done. Is the server not completing recovery and setting the recovery.conf to recovery.done because my recovery.conf is missing something?